# How can you test whether a user is active in Cakephp 2.0 auth component?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

I'm having trouble hashing out how to test whether a user is active using the new Auth component. I have 3 states a user can be in: 0 unactivated (default), 1 activated, 2 deactivated. I'm trying to implement this in the login function so I can return whether they haven't registered or have been banned.

**Login**:

```
        public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) {                   
                $results = $this->User->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('User.email' => $this->Auth->user('email')),
                    'fields' => array('User.is_active')
                ));
                if ($results['User']['is_active'] == 0) {
                    // User has not confirmed account
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has not been activated. Please check your email.');
                    $this->Auth->logout();
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));
                }
               // not working atm
                else if ($results['User']['is_active'] == 2) {
                    // User has been deactivated
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been deactivated. Contact site admin if you believe this is in error.');
                    $this->Auth->logout();
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));
                }
                else if ($results['User']['is_active'] == 1) {
                    // User is active
                      $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                    }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your email/password combination was incorrect'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Can't see where I've gone wrong. Users with admin privileges and activated users are still getting the unactivated account error.

**Update**

Decided to drop the User.is_active field and handle it all in roles. I'm handling it in the AppController and it is almost working now. In the isAuthorized function, it now throws errors if the user is banned or unactivated, but I need it to log them out as well.

```
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // This isAuthorized determines what logged in users are able to see on ALL controllers. Use controller
    // by controller isAuthorized to limit what they can view on each one. Basically, you do not want to allow
    // actions on all controllers for users. Only admins can access every controller.
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true; //Admin can access every action
    }
    elseif (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'unactivated') { // Account has not been activated
        $this->Session->setFlash("You haven't activated your account yet. Please check your email.");
        return false; 
    }
    elseif (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'banned') { // Your account has been banned
        $this->Session->setFlash("You're account has been banned. If you feel this was an error, please contact the site administrator.");
        return false;
    }
    return false; // The rest don't
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they log in, the User model info can be accessed with `$this->Auth->user()`. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    if ($this->Auth->user('is_active') == 0) {
        // User has not confirmed account
    } else if ($this->Auth->user('is_active') == 1) {
        // User is active

    // and so on
```

You can use `debug($this->Auth->user());` after the `login()` to see why the users keep showing as unactivated.

Comment: Keep getting this error while doing that: _Fatal error: Call to a member function user() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\deals\app\View\Layouts\default.ctp on line 103_

Comment: If you mean the `debug($this->Auth->user());`, you can only call it like that from the controller since it's a component. You can call it like this everywhere else: `debug(AuthComponent::user());`

Comment: So it looks like it is receiving the correct information so it has to be a fault with my logic. During login I need it to catch users who have been banned or users who have not confirmed their registration, and prompt them that they have been banned or they need to confirm their registration. Not sure if I'm even trying to do this in the right spot.

Comment: I would do it in the AppController::beforeFilter() function. Try putting the `debug()` just after the `if($this->Auth->login()) { ` instead of in the .ctp.

Comment: Also, if you update the user's data while they are logged in, the Auth->user() array needs to be updated as well if you're going to use it. It doesn't update it automatically.

Comment: Do you log a user in from your AppController? I currently have it coming from my users controller like it has on the 2.0 book.

Comment: No, I log in and out in UsersController. `$this->Auth->logout();` I suggest getting code completion going in your IDE.

Comment: I use NetBeans as well. Have you added the Cake directory to your include path on your project? If you type this: `$this->Auth->` then press ctrl+space, you should be able to see all the possible properties and methods for the `Auth` object.

Comment: Good call. Haven't added it, but am doing so now. You're fully of good tips.

Answer (score 0):

Now, in year 2021, for CakePHP 4.x this is the correct approach:

```
if ( $result->isValid() ) {

   if ( $this->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity')->is_active ) {
      // The user is active and can log in
   } else {
      // The user is not active - reject the log in
   }
}
```